# Build a map from conditional output values in terraform

Tags: terraform

I have a module that outputs two values, `key` and `value`. The module contains a third value `is_needed`, which is a boolean. I can run this module any number of times and get a map of the outputs. Is there a way to conditionally add values to a map based on the `is_needed` boolean?

For example, I can create a map with **all** of the values like this:

```
locals {
  map_of_values = tomap({
    for instance in module.my_module : instance.key => instance.value
  })
}
```

Can I create a map with only **some** of the values? Something akin to this pseudo-code:

```
locals {
  map_of_needed_values = tomap({
    for instance in module.my_module if is_needed: instance.key => instance.value
  })
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. In fact your pseudo code is very close to the correct syntax.

```
locals {
  map_of_needed_values = tomap({
    for instance in module.my_module :
    instance.key => instance.value if instance.is_needed
  })
}
```

Here's a full block of functioning code that will help you see it all working. I was not completely sure of the structure of your `module.my_module` outputs, so I guessed.

```
variable "my_module" {
  default = {
    "instance_1" = {
      "key"       = "hello"
      "value"     = "world"
      "is_needed" = false
    }
    "instance_2" = {
      "key"       = "foo"
      "value"     = "bar"
      "is_needed" = true
    }
  }
}

locals {
  map_of_needed_values = tomap({
    for instance in var.my_module :
    instance.key => instance.value if instance.is_needed
  })
}

output "map_of_needed_values" { value = local.map_of_needed_values }
```